# How to determine if outlook item is displayed

Tags: email, post, outlook, vsto

I'm building an Outlook add-in in Visual Studio 2010, using VSTO with VB.net.

For now I am processing mail items and post items. Is there a way to determine if a mail item or a post item is currently displayed?

All I want to do is close all displayed(open) items (if any) before I move them from their current folder to another.

I have googled this a lot but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check the [`MailItem.EntryID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.entryid) property to see whether a mail item exists in the collection of [`Application.Inspectors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868935%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and has an [`Inspector.CurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._inspector.currentitem.aspx)  associated to it with the same `EntryID`. Below is a useful helper method I've used in the past.

**Note:** This technique [doesn't work for new messages (composing) since new mail items don't contain an `EntryID` until they are saved/sent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.entryid).

```cs
internal static bool HasInspector(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
{
    bool HasInspector = false;
    try {
        if (mailItem == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailItem.EntryID)) return HasInspector; // short-circuit invalid params or new mail message (no entryid since it's not saved)
        foreach (Outlook.Inspector inspector in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Inspectors)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem currentMailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (currentMailItem != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentMailItem.EntryID))
            {
                HasInspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CompareEntryIDs(currentMailItem.EntryID, mailItem.EntryID);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(currentMailItem); currentMailItem = null; // resource RCW cleanup
            }
        }         
    }
    catch { } // attempt to request inspector for mailitem
    return HasInspector;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not correct. The `mailItem.GetInspector` call will create and display a new Inspector if the mail item doesn't already have one. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868098(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: @HughHughTeotl - great catch! I updated the method to reflect this. This was also creating us issues because `GetInspector` was creating the `Inspector` instead of checking whether it existed. Following @Dmitry and your suggestion to properly resolve.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found so far is to loop through `Application.Inspectors` (remember it's a 1-based collection not 0-based) and see if any of the inspectors have a `CurrentItem` equal to your mail item.

You can't use `MailItem.GetInspector` because that will create an inspector window for the mail item if one doesn't already exist.

Hopefully someone will be able to provide a better solution if one exists!

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the inspectors in the Application.Inspectoes collection, for each inspector read the CurrentItem property (it can return objects of different types, e.g. MailItem, ContactItem, etc.). Read the EntryID property and compare it with the entry id of the item in question using Namespace.CompareEntryIDs.